# Unsupported operand types: string + int

Tags: php

I have read through quite a few of the other posts regarding this error. But I am having no luck sorting it out on my own. This script takes some text and reads it and converts it to an xml format. This loop is looking for specific text and if its not present it throws the error.

I have tried casting the value as a integer but still end up with the error in php 8. The error is pointing to line 62 which is $i+=10;

If I dump $pbcs_ots_levels it is showing `array(0) { }` If I dump $i it is showing `string(0) ""`
I have tried casting integer to $i with no change. So I was hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction.

Thanks for taking a look
SC

```
if(strpos($line,'END OF PART ')!==false || strpos($line,'REMARKS')!==false)
            {
                
                
                if(strpos($line,'REMARKS')!==false)
                {
                    $line = fgets($handle);
                    $dt=[];
                    $dt['tmi']=trim(get_string_between($line,'TMI IS ',' '));
                    do
                    {
                        $line = fgets($handle);
                    }while(strpos($line,'PBCS OTS LEVELS')!==false);
                    
                    $pbcs_ots=get_string_between($line,'PBCS OTS LEVELS','.');
                    $pbcs_ots=explode('-',$pbcs_ots);
                    $i=$pbcs_ots[0];
                    
                    while($i<=$pbcs_ots[1])
                    {
                        //var_dump($pbcs_ots_levels);
                        $pbcs_ots_levels[]=$i;
                        //var_dump($i);
                        $i+=10;
                    }
                    
                    do
                    {
                        $line = fgets($handle);
                        
                        if(strpos($line,'TRACK ')!==false)
                        {
                            $pbcs_tracks[]=$line[6];
                        }
                    }while(strpos($line,'4.')===false);
```

Comment: An empty string `""` does not "nicely" convert to an int without casting it. You use `intval()` to do so without causing errors. E.g. update to `$i = intval($pbcs_ots[0])`

Comment: Thanks Rylee, I added intval and it threw another error, but at least in got past the integer error . Thank you for your help!